# How to make Abstract Syntax Tree of few line of code not a complete file or class in java?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, automated-tests, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to compare CFGs using AST comparison. I have tried the Eclipse AST Parser, it's great. But I'm using IntelliJ IDE so can't use it. I explored the Java parser but it returns compilation unit and work on complete Java files. Please suggest a way or APIs to get the Abstract Syntax Trees of basic blocks (few lines of code), further in I should be able to compare generated ASTs.

Comment: According to https://www.programcreek.com/2011/01/a-complete-standalone-example-of-astparser/ Eclipse's ASTParser can be used outside Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Now I m worried about how to compare it , I mean semantically.

Comment: Did you try https://javaparser.org/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never done this but what about taking the text of the basic block and putting a trivial wrapper around it:

```
class AST {
    void method() {
        // basic block here
    }
}
```

And passing that to the parser? It would give you more than you wanted, but you could navigate a couple of nodes down in the AST and the entire subtree below that would be the AST you wanted.

Comment: ... and if I hand you a random bit of Java, just exactly how are you going to decide what to wrap around it so it can be parsed?  Yes, its easy if somebody gives you chunk of code that is claimed to be a complete method.  Otherwise not so obvious.  Maybe that works for OP's narrow application if he indeed only parses methods... He already says he's interested in basic blocks, not just methods.

Comment: @Ira a basic block can only appear inside a method, and is more restrictive than what can appear in a method, since it can't include any control flow constructs. So any [basic block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_block) can always be wrapped as above.